# Bootstrap conflicts with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I was trying to add a show more/less function using toggle in my web page. But the toggle doesn't work when Bootstrap features work. I'm new to front-end developing, tried many solutions according to things I could find on the web but still no luck. Can anyone please help?

Below are (part of) my html file and jQuery file. I deleted all the lines that reference Bootstrap or jQuery since they were no use.

```js
var $j = $.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    init_nav();
    
    $j("p.catg").click(function(){
        $j(this).next(".nav_sub").slideToggle(100);
    });
    
    $j(".v_container #catalogy_more").click(function(){
        var el = $j(".special_selector .hidden");
        if(el.css("display")=="none"){ 
            el.stop().slideDown(300);
            $j(this).html('<span>Show Less</span><i class="b-icon b-icon-toggle-up"></i>');
        }
        else{
            el.stop().slideUp(300);
            $j(this).html('<span>Show More</span><i class="b-icon b-icon-toggle-down"></i>');
        }
    })
});
function init_nav(){
    $j(".nav_sub a").each(function(i, e) {
        var e = $j(e);
        if(e.hasClass("on")){
            e.parents("li").addClass("on");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="page_container">
      <!-- Game title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="game_title">
            <h2></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     
      <!-- Summary & game metadata -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- summary -->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
          <div class="summary">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Game metadata -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="v_container">
            <div class="v_selector">
              <div class="special_selector">
                <!-- Show content here-->
                <div class="shown">
                  <h4>Game Title:</h4>
                  <h4>Alternate Title:</h4>
                  <h4>Gameplay Genre:</h4>
                </div>
                <!-- Hidden content -->
                <div class="hidden">
                  <h4>Narrative Genre:</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="b-toggle-block">
                    <a class="b-toggle-btn" id="catalogy_more">
                      <span>Show More</span>
                      <i class="b-icon b-icon-toggle-down"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `class="nav_sub"` in your HTML?

Comment: I actually copied this chunk of jquery code from somewhere else, and nav_sub was used for another function in that page which I don't need in mine.

Comment: I suppose it is working fine. Please see this - https://jsfiddle.net/fq51dcxk/

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap and jQuery are you using?

Comment: How can I reply a comment? To Developer107, though it works in jsfiddle, it doesn't locally. So I think the problem is lying in referencing Bootstrap and jQuery which jsfiddle knows how to do correctly

Comment: To azeós, I'm actually not sure about which version of jQuery I'm using... I tried several latest ones. As to Bootstrap, I'm using the newest version.

Comment: The problem is with the Bootstrap CSS. You have a class `hidden` and that's a `display: none` for Bootstrap. You have to remove the class on `slideDown` and add it on `slideUp`.

Comment: I tried and it works now!!! Thank you so much :D